# Where to find instance I need

Tags: google-compute-engine

I reserved GPU instance with V100, but got difficulties with V100 driver, Cuda and Cudnn installation.

So please let me know where I can find preinstalled (Cuda and Cudnn) images and how them deploy to any instance?

Best Regards,
Tigran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a VM with GPU with cloud console - when selecting "create instance" select the "GPU" type and then you can add desired GPU ([availability may very depending on the zone you're in](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/gpu-regions-zones)).

There's a lot of gcp-provided images ready to use for new VM's - since you didn't specify your requirements or goals have a look at the "[Choosing an image](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/images)" documentation.

Or you can use one of the [contenerised deep learning images](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-containers/docs/choosing-container).

And if you want to create your own environment from scratch then create new VM with GPU and install the drivers. I've found this very handy [tutorial how to install them in GCP VM](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-cuda-on-google-cloud-platform-in-10-minutes-9525d874c8c1) which you may find helpful since it's not always quite easy.